# Silence Dart Sass Deprecation warning with craco

Tags: webpack, sass, craco

I'm getting hundreds of these warnings when I start my app with `npm run dev`:

```
    ╷
227 │ $pill--small-radius: 8px / 50%;
    │                      ^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    node_modules/.pnpm/@paprika+tokens@0.1.18_wcqkhtmu7mswc6yz4uyexck3ty/node_modules/@paprika/tokens/lib/tokens.scss 227:22  @import
    src/utils/RobotsHelpers.scss 1:9                                                                                          @import
    src/components/Test/Test.scss 1:9                                               root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(12px, 50%)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div
```

I'd like to silence those warnings as they are coming from third party libraries.

Going to the link in the warning, the page says: "Remember, you can silence deprecation warnings from libraries you don’t control! If you’re using the command-line interface you can pass the --quiet-deps flag, and if you’re using the JavaScript API you can set the quietDeps option to true."

Here is my craco.config.js, including the things that I have tried to no avail:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: { ... },
  eslint: { ... },
  style: {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: (cssLoaderOptions, { env, paths }) => {
        ...
        return {
          ...cssLoaderOptions,
          modules: {
            compileType: 'icss',
            // sassOptions: { quietDeps: true },    // THIS CAUSES AN ERROR
          },
        };
      },
    },

    // sass: {     // THIS CAUSES AN ERROR
    //   loaderOptions: {
    //     quietDeps: true,
    //   },
    // },

    // sass: {     // THIS DOESNT STOP WARNINGS
    //   loaderOptions: {
    //     sassOptions: { quietDeps: true },
    //   },
    // },
  },
};
```

The relevant part of my package.json:

```
"@craco/craco": "^5.8.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"sass": "^1.49.8",
```

How can I suppress those division warnings with craco? Thank you.

Comment: firstly you cannot divide different units with each other in `sass` or even in `css` (i think). Secondly, As the warning states "Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0." From now on you need to add `@use sass:math` as the first line of your `*.scss` file in order to implement calculations and then use it like `math.div(numerator, denominator)`.

Comment: @KunalTanwar thanks but I think you missed these parts of my original question:  "as they are coming from third party libraries" and "How can I suppress those division warnings with craco"